# How can I render the bitmap property of a .NET Compact Framework custom control in the Visual Studio form designer?

Tags: visual-studio, compact-framework, custom-controls

I have a custom control (inheriting from `control`; targeting .NET Compact Framework v2) that has a bitmap property.

Currently an instance of the control on the form designer will only paint the selected background color and writes the `namespace.control.name` overtop.

How can I have the image be rendered by the form designer after it's selected in the property editor?

**Edit**: The control is fairly basic but I am overriding `onpaint` and `onpaintbackground`

**Edit2**: In an effort to determine the cause I wrote a much simpler control. It's just a bitmap property and a call to `graphics.drawimage` in `onpaint` (so a cheap `imagebutton`). This too fails to render. I even included a check to make sure it wasn't trying to render a null image and never refreshing or anything, but no luck.

Comment: I hope you get a real answer, but I have to comment here that getting a custom control to render properly at runtime can be difficult enough. Trying to get it to also look right in the designer can be a lot more work for virtually no gain (unless this is a third-party thing you're planning to sell).

Comment: And once you get it working, you have to try to get it working yet again for CF 3.5.  I'd totally agreen that getting the designer to get it right is almost never worth the effort.

Comment: thats not very reassuring :( ... at least it's for internal use and i can skip getting it to render properly

Answer (score 0):

Are you manually painting (i.e. overriding OnPaint and drawing that Bitmap out)?  Generally speaking rendering in the designer for a very basic control should work.

You'll get the box with the control name if the designer hits something that it can't handle (a P/Invoke fore example) and so often you have to "protect" the device specific code from being called by the designer.

Try backing out functionality until it starts rendering properly to figure out where it's failing (becasue you can't really debug this stuff any other way).

Comment: I am overriding onpaint and drawing the bitmap - that's about as 'crazy' as it gets though, no p/invokes, or anything that shouldnt be in a control